# Android Studio - Error cannot find symbol class R while compiling OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-studio, compilation

I'm trying to compile a project with Opencv but I keep getting this problem: Error:(5, 18) error: cannot find symbol class R

The error is occurring in this: import org.opencv.R;

This is just a part of the code where I'm getting the error:

```
package br.raphael.extended;
import java.util.List;
import org.opencv.R;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;

import br.raphael.detector.FpsMeterExtended;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

/**
 * This is a basic class, implementing the interaction with Camera and OpenCV library.
 * The main responsibility of it - is to control when camera can be enabled, process the frame,
 * call external listener to make any adjustments to the frame and then draw the resulting
 * frame to the screen.
 * The clients shall implement CvCameraViewListener.
 */
public abstract class CameraBridgeViewBaseExtended extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraBridge";
    private static final int MAX_UNSPECIFIED = -1;
    private static final int STOPPED = 0;
    private static final int STARTED = 1;

    private int mState = STOPPED;
    private Bitmap mCacheBitmap;
    private CvCameraViewListener2 mListener;
    private boolean mSurfaceExist;
    private Object mSyncObject = new Object();

    protected int mFrameWidth;
    protected int mFrameHeight;
    protected int mMaxHeight;
    protected int mMaxWidth;
    protected int mPreviewFormat = Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA;
    protected int mCameraIndex = -1;
    protected boolean mEnabled;
    protected FpsMeterExtended mFpsMeter = null;

    public CameraBridgeViewBaseExtended(Context context, int cameraId) {
        super(context);
        mCameraIndex = cameraId;
    }

    public CameraBridgeViewBaseExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        int count = attrs.getAttributeCount();
        Log.d(TAG, "Attr count: " + Integer.valueOf(count));

        TypedArray styledAttrs = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase);
        if (styledAttrs.getBoolean(R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase_show_fps, false))
            enableFpsMeter();

        mCameraIndex = styledAttrs.getInt(R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase_camera_id, -1);

        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mMaxWidth = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
        mMaxHeight = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting error mentioning  `import org.opencv.R` , it means that there is error in some of your xml view page. Recheck your ***XML*** page

---

Comment: I think the problem may be here:   `TypedArray styledAttrs = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase);`         In the OpenCV res folder I have this attrs file that contains: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name = "CameraBridgeViewBase" >
       <attr name="show_fps" format="boolean"/>
       <attr name="camera_id" format="integer" >
          <enum name="any" value="-1" />
          <enum name="back" value="99" />
          <enum name="front" value="98" />
       </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>`